# Is Bumblebee required in 19.10?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I'm trying to optimise the power management on my Dell XPS 15 laptop, whose current consumption is approximately equivalent to the output of a midsized nuclear power plant.

I would therefore like to ensure that the hybrid graphics (Optimus) feature works as intended, and shuts off the dGPU when not in use. Do I still need to use Bumblebee and bbswitch to accomplish this, or has Ubuntu (and the kernel) advanced to the point where it's handled natively? I see that `prime-select` allows choosing one of the graphics processors or `--on-demand`.

System details:

```
Kubuntu 19.10
Dell XPS 15 9530
Intel i7-4702HQ with HD Graphics 4600
Nvidia GT750M (nvidia-driver-418 proprietary driver)
```

Comment: the prime-select option `--on-demand` is misleading: [How to use “prime-select on-demand” in latest Kubuntu 19.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1188458/how-to-use-prime-select-on-demand-in-latest-kubuntu-19-10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu's Optimus management dropped bbswitch in 18.10, later backported to 18.04. 
So you don't need it. The acpi calls are I think now supported by the kernel. .
If you use NVIDIA drivers, sudo prime-select Intel should turn off NVIDIA.
If it's  not working, it's a bug which you should report.. The Ubuntu devs take Optimus support seriously.